# Create dualboot from existing Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, windows, dual-boot

It so happens that I came to a point where I have two separate 120GB drives, one with Windows 10 and another with ArchLinux. They are working great, but at the time I can only choose one of them is through UEFI/BIOS menu. Is there a way I can create a dual-boot through GRUB or Windows boot manager so I have 3 seconds to choose an OS before booting?

Both OSs are fully configured and used, so I would really prefer to keep them intact, rather that re-install one of them. All instructions I have found are for fresh installations, none is for converting existing two boots into one dual boot.

Comment: with both drives plugged in, have you tried booting linux and running `update-grub`? many distributions will check for other operating systems automatically add them to your boot menu.

Comment: Instead of modifying either OS, you can use rEFInd as your boot manager. As I understand it, rEFInd will detect the EFI executables on all the ESPs on your system, allowing you to start the Windows 10 or Arch Linux boot managers from one menu. Of course, that means two menu systems are involved in booting an OS.

Comment: @PhilipCouling update-grub: command not found

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa thank you, I am trying to configure it now